# How does string concatenation (using + operator) work internally in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, express, get, string-concatenation

What are the limitations to using + operator in string concatenation, i.e. special characters or HTML tags?

There is a block of fixed code (of a plain working website). 
I get the code of one particular page - `www.example.com` 
Using **only changes in the URL** (in the browser itself) I have to navigate through different loops according to the given code. 
I do not get to change the code. 
I want to get to `answer`
My current output is `closed`. 
So, essentially I want to know what can **generate an error** in the try block :

```
<some code>

if (req.query.L.length>999){
  try {
    const a = "<" + req.query.L + ">"
    res.end(Closed.)
  } catch{
    res.end(answer)
  }
}
else{
...
}

<some code>
```

I started with `www.example.com` 
My current browser query looks like this `www.example.com/?L[length]=1000`

What is a way to achieve this?

Am I looking at the right place, i.e. string concatenation, or do I need to look at some limitation of req.query? Any helpful documentation will be beneficial too.
This is part of an ExpressJS codebase.

Comment: make sure to stringify `req.query.ques` first if it is an Object type

Comment: Well, the `+` operator will just join the strings naively. If you are trying to generate html/xml then you will need to ensure it is valid on top of the concatenation. In general it would be great if you could update your question with more specifics.

Comment: Updated question with the exact block of code I need solving.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking.  String concatenation just combines two strings and tries to coerce the second operand to a string if it isn't already one.  It does not look at the content at all so you're questions about HTML tags or special characters have nothing to do with string concatenation.  Whatever is in the two strings will be in the combined result string.  In your URL: `http://www.example.com/?L[length]=1000`, what are you trying to access from that?  You show `req.query.ques`, but there is no `ques` part in that URL.

Comment: Please show EXACTLY what you're trying to do.  Show what the URL is.  Show what `req.query.ques` is and show what result you get and show what result you're expecting that is different from what you get.  That's how you write a clear question that can be quickly answered.  Right now, you do not have a clear question that can be easily answer.

Comment: FYI, accessing a non-exist property on the `req.query` object such as `req.query.ques` does not throw an exception at all.  It just returned `undefined` as the value of that property.  That's how Javascript works.  You can manually test if the property exists with `if (req.query.hasOwnProperty('ques'))` or perhaps with `if (req.query.ques)` if falsey values are not expected.

Comment: I have updated my description of the question.

Answer (score -1):

Use regular expressions to only allow alpha numeric.

```
if(!req.query.ques || new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9]$", "gi").test(req.query.ques) == false)
{
    console.log("Invalid character not allowed");
}
```